# Elegant method to break recursively generated nested for loops in C++

Tags: c++, xml, recursion, pugixml

I have created a function (using PugiXML, specifically) to iterate all Document Tree nodes to find a specific node. To do this, I have created a function that contains a for loop which iterates through node siblings and is called recursively to iterate through the entire depth of the tree and find a specific node (not shown in the code). Although the specific use is not precisely relevant I have two main questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this? As I understand, this mixture of iterative and recursive logic is not a good coding practice. Does anyone else have suggestions on another method I should implement? Also, leading me to question 2:
2. Is there an elegant way to break MANY nested for loops? I use `goto` with my current code, but have been told that using it is a bad coding practice, and it definitely should not be used in a recursive algorithm. I also use two global variables because of the limitations

My code:

```
xml_node recursiveFind(xml_node node)
{

    for (node = node; node; node = node.next_sibling())
    {        
        if (checkAttr(node) == 0)
        {
            cout << "found: " << node.name() << " attr: " << node.first_attribute().value() << endl;
            found = true;
            foundNode = node;
            goto return_code;
        }
        else if (checkAttr(node) == 1 && found != true)
        {
            cout << "still looking: " << node.name() << " attr: " << node.first_attribute().value() << endl;
            recursiveFind(node.first_child());
        }

    return_code:
        return foundNode;

    }
```

For a quick walkthrough of my code, the for loop iterates through siblings, then a second function, `checkAttr()` is called with the current node as a parameter to check whether it is the node I am searching for, and if it returns 0 (true), a global variable is set that is supposed to stop the recursive call (in the following `else if` statement. Then, another global variable with the selected node is created so that it can be returned by the `goto` call. Adding any sort of break in the for loop is impossible as many, many, many nested loops are generated from the recursive calls. Hopefully, this question is able to also assist others using PugiXML.

Comment: The shown code appears to be fundamentally flawed, since the return value of the recursive call is completely discarded and thrown away. This cannot be correct. What is `found`? What is `foundNode`. Are they global variables? Global variables are bad.

Comment: Yes, the recursive call is flawed and is not really "recursive". Calling my code recursive honestly is a bit of a stretch. The not-shown checkAttr() function does the real work.

Comment: I pop the nested loops into a function and return from the function.

Comment: Depending on your use case the question might actually be should you be doing it this way or should you be using a map or other container that is made to make searching efficient. At the very least, if you use a std container you can pass the compare logic in as a lamda and not be locked into a single algorithm.

Comment: While nothing is wrong with `goto` in moderation the use here is just plain unnecessary. Replace the `goto` with `return foundNode;`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I did attempt to do that, but it didn't seem to work. I believe it's because the ```return``` call returns to the parent recursive call instead of returning the entire ```recursiveFind``` function. Please correct me if my understanding of the call stack is wrong.

Comment: @EthanJ True, return only returns one level. But that is also true with goto. As Sam Varshavchik already mentioned you ignore the return value in the recursive call and the `found` and `foundNode` make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I realized that I had missed a fundamental part of recursive functions, driver and recursive functions. Thank you to @user4581301 for your comment. For other PugiXML users, I would recommend using XPath as it is probably more optimized than anything you will write ;)